# Does Professor Shonku's pistol, Annihillin, have a limited number of shots?

Tags: weapon

How many times can [Professor Shonku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Shonku) fire the Annihillin, a pistol that sends enemies to other dimensions, at once? Is there a limit?

Comment: Down voters, please state the reason for down voting

Comment: Probably because the overwhelming majority of these books are written in a foreign language and untranslated.